# Is there any way to know the postpaid bill amount from android phone?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

Is there any way to know the  postpaid bill amount from android phone.
I think There is no API to access that sort of information from the SIM card in Android. If possible Any one suggest me is there any way to know the postpaid bill amount from phone.

Answer (score 0):

This information is not stored in the SIM card but on the provider's servers, so you would need to call their API (different for each operator).
I'm not even sure they allows third parties to access that kind of data.